# how to delete DBs from MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm having trouble to remove MySQL Databases that's what I'm getting, I'm using 5.6 MySql

when I hit show databases:

I'm having the list of dbs such as `gameserver_beta`, `loginserver_beta` and etc however, when I use command **`drop database <gameserver_beta>;`**

I'm getting an

> error 1064 (42000) yOu have an error in your SQL syntec, check the manuel that correspond to your MySQL server version ...

Answer (score 2):

```
drop database database_name;

drop database ;
```

Here you did not specified any database name

try wth this

Comment: It think it's worked this time thank you so much ! one more question how to remove a user - i want to rebuild my DB from a sractch.